# How to read a file from the last read position?

Tags: python, python-2.7, file

I have a 3,000,000,000 line text file. I use this command below to open it

```
with open("/data/tmp/tbl_show_follow.txt") as infile:
```

but sometimes I need to kill my Python scripts to stop reading this file, and next time I need to read from the last position I read. My current solution is using a `counter_i` to remember the position and print to the log every 100,000 lines

```
20161108 21:19  last position : 100000
20161108 22:34  last position : 200000
20161108 23:34  last position : 300000
.......
20161408 23:34  last position : 200000000
```

and I run python scripts again, I need to change condition like that

```
count_i = 0 
with open("/data/tmp/tbl_show_follow.txt") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if count_i > 300000:
            do sth ...
```

but if my last position is 200,000,000 and I stop my Python script, next time I need to read file from the beginning and count 1 to 200,000,000. I think its very stupid to do that, how to begin from the 200,000,000th line? is there any method to remember the last position I read the file?

Comment: You can only jump in a file if you know the last read position in *bytes*, not in *lines*.

Comment: with a file with that many lines it might be worth while to break it into multiple files, i.e. tbl_show_follow.1.txt, tbl_show_follow.2.txt and so on. If you needed to keep track of how many lines you've processed in between killing and running the script, you could simply write which file to start from in a file every X lines. If that file doesn't exist you can start from the beginning. I would also recommend using a generator to read from the text to avoid saving anything in memory.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `file.tell()` to get the file’s current position (measured in bytes) and `file.seek()` to set it.

- [`file.tell()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.tell)
- [`file.seek()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek)

Answer (score 0):

You are here logging (or saving) the amount of lines read. The problem is that if you start reading a file, you don't know how long the lines are. For example consider a file that looks like this:

```
line1
line number two
line3
```

on your disk this file is saved as a continuous stream. like so (on unix):

```
line1\nline number two\nline3
```

Now, there is no way to know beforehand where line3 starts, because that depends on how long line1 and line3 are. And you can only know this once you read them, and find out where the `\n` characters are.

So your simple solution would be to log/save the actual file position you are at. This is the `tellf()` you see in the other answers. This is the current character you are at in your file. So you still don't know how many lines are before that, but you at least know that that is where you left of last time.